# How do I set o365 browser version of Microsoft Excel as the default editor for xlsx files in my Chromebook My Files folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, office365, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Chromebook w/OS v88.x

Microsoft 365 Family subscription

Situation:
I have a file in my Chromebook's My Files folder called 'test.xlsx'. Currently, if I double-click on it, it will open that file in Google Sheets in my browser.

I would like to have it open the file in Microsoft Excel online in my browser instead.

I don't want to install or use the Excel app on my Chromebook (from the store).

I'd like to do the same with Word and Powerpoint files, too.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Double clicking on an Office file doesn't open it in your browser but in the "Office Editing for Docs, Sheets, and Slides" mini-app that is local to the Chromebook and, in general, there is no way to open a web app from a file in Downloads.  You have to open Excel Online in your browser first and upload it.